# Structuring PHP conditional over HTML and PHP blocks

Tags: php

I wish to do something like this:

```
<?php if ($somecondition) : ?>
<p style='font-size: 18px;color:#DF5F5F'><strong>An error occurred!</strong></p>
<!-- some more html -->

<?php else:
  chop($xpath);
  $alot;
  $ofphp;
?>

<ul>
<li>More</li>
<li>HTML</li>
<li>With: <?php echo strtoupper($vaiables); ?></li>
</ul>

<?php
  if ($anothercondition) {
    if ($andanother) {
      echo '<p>Some HTML</p>';
    }
    else {
      echo '<p>Some other HTML</p>';
    }
  }
endif;
?>
```

As you can see I want the whole to be surrounde by one condition `$somecondition` and its else alternative. Inside each there is room for HTML output *and* PHP. However, I don't want to use echo for each HTML element (as you can see in the second line).

Is it possible to mix `if ($condition):` and `if ($condition() {}`, and how? How I would I correctly structure the above code without having to use echo in the `$anothercondition` block?

Comment: I think your code should work as written. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Barmar I had a 500 server error, so I thought this was the error. After further investigation I forgot a parenthesis somewhere...

Comment: If you use a good code editor, it will identify problems like that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem with mixing the brace and colon style of control flow statements. The only requirement is that if you use a particular style for `if`, you have to use the same style for its corresponding `else` and `elseif` clauses, i.e. you **can't** write

```
if ($cond):
    // code
else {
    // other code
}
endif;
```

But when you're nesting them, you can use different styles at each level.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this:

```
<?php
if ($somecondition) {
    ?>
    html code
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
    html code
    <?php
    if ($anothercondition) {
        ?>
        another html code
        <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use brackets consistently? also gives for clearer code in my opinion:

```
<?php if ($somecondition) { ?>
<p style='font-size: 18px;color:#DF5F5F'><strong>An error occurred!</strong></p>
<!-- some more html -->

<?php } else {
  chop($xpath);
  $alot;
  $ofphp;
?>

<ul>
<li>More</li>
<li>HTML</li>
<li>With: <?php echo strtoupper($vaiables); ?></li>
</ul>

<?php }
  if ($anothercondition) {
    if ($andanother) {
      echo '<p>Some HTML</p>';
    }
    else {
      echo '<p>Some other HTML</p>';
    }
  }
?>
```